# How do I import a ta (true average range/ atr) into TadingView Pine Editor for Pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Im trying to create/code a strategy in trading view where I need the code to extract info from the "atr" or "ta" and im always getting a syntax error when i try to compile the code.

[screenshot of error code and where code is located in the editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTBpU.png)

I hope to be able to Import the information for the code to work. If I need to create a Library then how do I go about it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to finish the code of what you are trying to import. 'Import tar' isn't valid. You can get the atr using the inbuilt function, no need to import it or a library.

```
atr = ta.atr(14)
```